# Why does my tkinter window not display the expected output from an invoked subproccess

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess

In this code i am trying to finger users from a domain to return their credentials, but when i actually call the finger command in variable pep and have it displayed in the variable results which gets packed into a tkinter window. When i run it the only thing that is displayed is a '0' and i can see the finger command run properly and return the correct info the background Debug I/O but it does not display it in the tkinter window, i have no idea why. Any help? (P.S. for anyone running the code, entering a blank string on the finger_target returns a list on all users online)

```
        import tkinter,subprocesses,time
        from tkinter import *    
        root=Tk()    
        finger_target,fingerlabel=Entry(root),Label(root, text="TARGET: ")
        finger_confirm=Button(root, text="FINGER", command=lambda: TheActualfinger(finger_target.get()))
        finger_target.grid(row=0, column=1)
        fingerlabel.grid(row=0,column=0)
        finger_confirm.grid(row=0, column=2)
        def TheActualfinger(user):                      

              pep=subprocess.call(("finger",finger_target.get()+"@telehack.com"))
              outfinger= Tk()
              def windowCalsDEFAULT():
                      w,h =500, 500
                      ws, hs=outfinger.winfo_screenwidth(),outfinger.winfo_screenheight()
                      x, y=(ws/2) - (w/2),(hs/2) - (h/2)
                      outfinger.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))        
                      results= Label(outfinger, text=pep).pack(fill="x")
                      outfinger.mainloop()
        root.mainloop()
```

Comment: put code again and use button `{}` to correctly format code on SO. Now it is unreadable.

Comment: always read documentation. [subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) "... return the returncode attribute."

Comment: As @furas points out, the indentation of the code in your question makes it unintelligible. Please [edit] your question and fix this.

Comment: read documentation: [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) `"Run command with arguments and return its output."`

Comment: BTW: `tkinter` should have only one window `Tk()`. To create second/third window use `Toplevel()` (or use `tkinter.messagebox.showinfo` to display message). `tkinter` should have only one `mainloop()` - if you use two `mainloop` then `tkinter` works incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) returns only status code - error code returned by `finger` - and `0` means `OK`.

Use [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to get text.

BTW: `tkinter` should have only one `Tk()` window (main window). To create other windows use `Toplevel()`. And `tkinter` should have only one `mainloop` (it is its `"engine"`)

BTW: you can use `tkinter.messagebox.showinfo` to display window with message.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox
import subprocess

# --- functions ---

def window_with_result(text):

    win = tk.Toplevel()

    w = 500
    h = 500
    ws = win.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = win.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (ws-w)/2
    y = (hs-h)/2

    win.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))        
    tk.Label(win, text=text, justify='left').pack(fill="x")

def actual_finger(user):                      
    result = subprocess.check_output(["finger", user+"@telehack.com"])

    print('[DEBUG]:', result)

    # message window
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(user, result)

    # or own window
    window_with_result(result)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

target = tk.Entry(root)
label = tk.Label(root, text="TARGET: ")
confirm = tk.Button(root, text="FINGER", command=lambda:actual_finger(target.get()))

target.grid(row=0, column=1)
label.grid(row=0, column=0)
confirm.grid(row=0, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

---

BTW: I use `lower_case` names to make code more readable.

See [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)